# R: Match specific elements from a list of data frames and create new data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

Let's have a list of data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c("a", "b", "c"),V2=c("d", "e","f"), V3=c("g","h","i"),V4=c("j","k","l"))
df2 <- data.frame(V1=c("m","n"), V2=c("o","p"), V3=c("q","r"))
l <-list(df1, df2)
> l
[[1]]
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  a  d  g  j
2  b  e  h  k
3  c  f  i  l

[[2]]
  V1 V2 V3
1  m  o  q
2  n  p  r
```

Moreover, we have a vector:

```
ele <- c("a","b","e","g","i","m","p","s","t")
```

I want to obtain a new data frame contructed by matching elements from vector `ele` and list `l`. Data frame should have colnames from matched elemenets from vector and element right to the matches elements from the list.
For instance:

```
df3 <-data.frame(a="d",b='e',e="h",g="j",i="l",m="o",p="r")
> df3
  a b e g i m p
1 d e h j l o r
```

As you may notice there is not spefic matching pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there's better solutions somewhere, but this is a possibility:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

l %<>%
  map(~ t(.x) %>% 
        as_tibble() %>% 
        flatten_chr())


ele %>%
  map(~ map(l, equals, .x)) %>% 
  map_chr(~ {
    lgl <- map_lgl(.x, any)
    if (!any(lgl)) {
      NA
    } else {
      lgl_idx <- min(which(lgl))
      lgl     <- l[[lgl_idx]]
      lgl[min(which(.x[[lgl_idx]])) + 1]
    }
  }) %>%
  set_names(ele) %>%
  na.omit()
```

Needs some more exception handling (such as when the vector equals an element in the last column) but it works on the example you've given.

```
  a   b   e   g   i   m   p 
"d" "e" "h" "j" "l" "o" "r"
```

Comment: This is quite complicated example for me but it works fine in both the given example and my work dataset. Thanks! Chapeau bas!

Answer (score 0):

You can fine the element that matches an argument using `which`, and then add a vector to it (in this case `c(0,1)`).

```
ele_list = as.list(ele)
names(ele_list) = ele
unlist(lapply(ele_list, function(e) df1[which(df1 == e, arr.ind = TRUE)  + c(0, 1)]))

  a   b   e   g   i 
"d" "e" "h" "j" "l"
```

I only did it for `df1`, you could run the third line for both, then combine the vectors and convert to dataframe.

Comment: Could you provide the function for the `l` list?